# 30 mil records into 700 mil lookup, best practices - SQL Server 08

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, loops, insert

I have a SQL Script that looks at 30-40 "codes" for various conditions and finds matching records from a large 2-table (joined on PK) source of about 30 million rows. After the script completes, I end up with a lookup table of nearly 800+ mil. records (25 mil * ~35 codes).

Each code has its own select statement. Most of them are looking at the same source, just using a different condition. A few codes' queries join an additional source table to get the lookup_value.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO LookupTable 
SELECT 01 AS code, t1.lookup_value, t1.PK, t2.PK
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.FK = t2.PK
WHERE <code 1 condition> = true

INSERT INTO LookupTable     
SELECT 02 AS code, t1.lookup_value, t1.PK, t2.PK
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.FK = t2.PK
WHERE <code 2 condition> = true

INSERT INTO LookupTable     
SELECT 03 AS code, CASE WHEN t1.lookup_value IN 'A1','B1','C1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, t1.PK, t2.PK
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.FK = t2.PK
WHERE <code 3 condition> = true

INSERT INTO LookupTable     
SELECT 04 AS code, CASE WHEN t3.lookup_value IN 'A1','B1','C1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, t1.PK, t2.PK
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.FK = t2.PK
JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.FK = t3.PK
WHERE <code 4 condition> = true

 --  ... <continues 30 more times>
```

(There are also multi-query statements, temp tables, etc. for some of the codes, but if I can handle the above, I can figure those out on my own.)

As it stands now, the script takes about 6 hours to run on a powerful server. This is for a pre-existing system and I don't have the option of re-designing how it works; the huge lookup table is required.

I can't help but think that scanning through the same 30 mil. rows, 30+ times is an inefficient approach! Any thoughts for better performance, or at the very least, more manageable code?

I've been considering either creating a .Net CLR TVF, or an indexed view, but I'm open to new ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that any condition can be met only one time.

Then it's a simple one (careful, untested!):

```
INSERT INTO LookupTable 
SELECT
  code = c.val
  t1.lookup_value, 
  t1.PK, 
  t2.PK
FROM 
  Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2 
    ON t1.FK = t2.PK
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT val = CASE 
      WHEN <code 1 condition> THEN 01
      WHEN <code 2 condition> THEN 02
      ...
      WHEN <code 34 condition> THEN 34 
      ELSE 00 END
  ) v
WHERE c.val != 99
```

If my assumption != true, then I believe you (or somebody) should rethink the design.

Comment: This works - I had to include a table for my codes so FROM Table1 JOIN table2 turns into FROM (SELECT * FROM tblCodes, Table1 JOIN Table2), and I get the 20+ mil per code as expected. Still need to see if there are performance gains though.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** updated answer

Use a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to pre-parse your 30 million records tables into a temporary result set, and then do several insert-selects off of that...

```
WITH Table_CTE (code, lookup_value, pk1, pk2)
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN <code 1 condition> THEN 01
        CASE WHEN <code 2 condition> THEN 02
        CASE WHEN <code 3 condition> THEN 03
        CASE WHEN <code 4 condition> THEN 04
        ...
    END code, t1.lookup_value, t1.PK as pk1, t2.PK as pk2
    FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.FK = t2.PK
    JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.FK = t3.PK
)

INSERT INTO LookupTable
SELECT code, lookup_value, pk1, pk2
FROM Table_CTE
WHERE code = '01'

INSERT INTO LookupTable
SELECT code, lookup_value, pk1, pk2
FROM Table_CTE
WHERE code = '02'

INSERT INTO LookupTable
SELECT code, lookup_value, pk1, pk2
FROM Table_CTE
WHERE code = '03'
```

Comment: This will only give me the matches from one code, so 30 mil. rows when I need 30 mil. for each code.